# in slideToggle how to auto roll to a li with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scrollbar

http://jsfiddle.net/sdgwbyv8/

I use a JQUERY slideToggle to open a div

there are many rows.

I need when the user click #list_button or before click.

the div scrollbar will be auto roll to `<li class="now>`

```
<h1 id="list_button">open</h1>
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>AAAAA</li>
        <li>BBBBB</li>
        <li>CCCCC</li>
        <li>DDDDD</li>
        <li>EEEEE</li>  
        <li>DDDDD</li>
        <li>EEEEE</li>  
        <li>DDDDD</li>
        <li>DDDDD</li>
        <li>EEEEE</li>  
        <li>DDDDD</li>
        <li>DDDDD</li>
        <li>EEEEE</li>  
        <li>DDDDD</li>
        <li class="now">EEEEE</li>  
        <li>DDDDD</li>
        <li>EEEEE</li>        
    </ul>

</div>

$( "#list_button" ).click(function() {
        $( ".list" ).slideToggle( "fast" );
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( "#list_button" ).click(function() {
   $( ".list" ).slideToggle( "fast" , function() {
          var scrollTo = $(".now");
          $( ".list" ).animate({
          scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - $( ".list" ).offset().top + $( ".list" ).scrollTop()
        });
    });
});
```

this should scroll to the desired target when open.

Answer (score 1):

Opens the list and then scrolls to the desired list item ONLY after the list has completed the opening animation. Note that scrollTo in the accepted answer is equal to any item on the page with a class of now while mine is limited to any list item with a class of now in the selected list.

```
$( "#list_button" ).click(function() {
    $( ".list" ).slideToggle( "fast", function(){
      $(this).animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).find('li.now').offset().top
      },500);
    });
 });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sdgwbyv8/6/)